# Changing background color in wordpress element

Tags: css

I'm working on a site for our clinic, here: www.markshoushadentistry.com

I am trying to change the background on the pages (not home page) from white to a textured image background. I've located using Inspect in Chrome the CSS is:

```
.site-content {
    background: #FFF;
}
```

But I can't seem to find where it is to change it. There is an option in customizer that changes the color of the background, but I'm trying to change the background to an image.

Can anyone tell me where the code is to change the background color to an image?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: background-image: url("something.jpg"); something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.site-content` is overriden by another top CSS

```
.home .site-content {
    background: none;
}
```

if you change your CSS with:

```
.home .site-content {
    background: #fff !important;
}
```

it should work

Comment: Hm.. Thanks so much for the response and help, but that still doesn't seem to be working. I am using 'Advanced CSS Editor' for Wordpress to make the change, and when I add the .site-content {background: url("url.com"}; it seems it's being overwritten by another file, for example, in Inspect in chrome I see this:

https://imgur.com/a/Qbq4t

I'm just confused on where it is being overwritten and how I can prevent that.

Comment: try to add !important flag to your css

Comment: adding `!important` is a bad manner... you should locate and disable the other background definition

Comment: You should start by using the developer tools of the browser you are using and selecting the element to find what styles are being used on it so that you can override them

Answer (score 0):

To change background color in a wordpress you can follow the following steps :

1. Login to wordpress and open dashboard
2. Go to Customizer (Appearance > Customize) -> Additional css
3. Enter the CSS to change the background color. Below is sample code:

[image]

- site is the css class for the whole site.
- XXXXXX is the hex code for the color you want to use.

> you can choose your color code from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp)

4. Click Update File

And your background color will change . Hope this helps you